# Parsing float fom text file and sorting it in descending order

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, sorting, text

i need a little help with sorting text rows.

```
Kazimira Danutė PRUNSKIENĖ : 3,86%
Dalia GRYBAUSKAITĖ : 68,21%
Valdemar TOMAŠEVSKI : 4,68%
Algirdas BUTKEVIČIUS : 11,68%
Valentinas MAZURONIS : 6,08%
Česlovas JEZERSKAS : 0,66%
Loreta GRAUŽINIENĖ : 3,57%
```

I need to sort this text document by numbers.

```
Dalia GRYBAUSKAITĖ : 68,21%
Algirdas BUTKEVIČIUS : 11,68%
Valentinas MAZURONIS : 6,08%
Valdemar TOMAŠEVSKI : 4,68%
Kazimira Danutė PRUNSKIENĖ : 3,86%
Loreta GRAUŽINIENĖ : 3,57%
Česlovas JEZERSKAS : 0,66%
```

What is best way to do this?

```
           Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(desktopPath + "/RINKIMAI/INFO.txt"), "UTF-8");
           @SuppressWarnings("resource")
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

          java.util.List<Float> allMatches = new ArrayList<Float>();
           String word = null;
           while((word =br.readLine()) != null){
               Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+,\\d+");
               Matcher m = p.matcher(word); 
               while (m.find()) {
                   allMatches.add(Float.parseFloat(m.group()));   
               }
               Arrays.sort(allMatches);
           }
```

I'm unable to put all parsed information into array, because it's float type, can't find solution.. And still is it possible after sorting all info in descending to bring back full rows with all information in descending?

Comment: You need to create a class that has fields for the name and float, and implements `Comparable`.

Comment: You need to add the string and the float as a single entry, and sort of the float alone using a custom Comparator.

Comment: By the way, just in case you don't _have_ to have this in Java, and just need to sort the file, you can do this in Bash: `sort -t ':' -k2,2 -nr myfile.txt`

Comment: So this way isn't right one, which i'm using now. i have never used Comparators and all that stuff, don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

> NumberFormat

and

> Collections.sort

Like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException, ParseException {
     Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream("test.txt"), "UTF-8");
     @SuppressWarnings("resource")
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
     NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

    java.util.List<Float> allMatches = new ArrayList<Float>();
     String word = null;
     while((word =br.readLine()) != null){
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+,\\d+");
         Matcher m = p.matcher(word); 
         while (m.find()) {
             Number number = format.parse(m.group());
             allMatches.add(number.floatValue());   
         }
//         Arrays.sort(allMatches);
         Collections.sort(allMatches);
     }

     for (Float float1 : allMatches) {
        System.out.println(float1);
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible after sorting float values get all string information back?

Comment: in that case you will need to put all information in the form of object. The object will have a String storing the text data and another float attribute holding the number. Then you need to implement custom comparator, which you will pass to collections.sort